# Image shape has 3 dimensions, but format is incorrect when I test using numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing

I have an image that has the following shape `(170, 1920, 3)`. The first two numbers are the dimensions and the third is is the RGB value. So three sets of arrays of size (170,1920). Each array representing either red, green or blue value.

Now I created a test array using the following code:

```
a=np.zeros((5,6,3))
print(a)
print(a.shape)
```

and the output I get is:

```
(5, 6, 3)
[[[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]]]>
```

This doesn't make sense to me, because shouldn't the output look something like this?

```
[[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]]
```

It should be 3 sets of arrays, each being (6x5). The array above is created by using `a=np.zeros((3,5,6))`. But then why isn't my image also shaped like `(3,170,1920)`

Comment: In numpy, the last dimension is inner most. It's **displaying** it as 5 blocks of  (6,3) arrays.

Comment: You should convert your image to a numpy array and print it, and you'll see that it is not in fact a separate 170*1920 array for each color channel and instead a single 170*1920 array with 3 values at each 'pixel'

Comment: `(n,m,3)` is a shape that many image processing functions expect - such as the `cv` loader and various image display functions.  Printing it as `n` blocks of (m,3) is just the normal `numpy` way of displaying a 3d array, regardless of the "meaning" of the various dimensions.  It's easy to swap dimensions, to put, for example the 3 first, but that usually not necessary to using the array as a image.  I stress, the print order is just a display thing, not a fundamental "property" of the array.